# Subclassed UIView doesn't get tag set

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, subclass

I have subclassed a `UIView` class and I create multiple instances of this class in a loop (incrementing each time), however when I try to set the tag of the view, and log it to the console after they are all created, they all have a tag of 1, regardless of what I set the tag as.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

My Code for creating the subview is here:

```
//for() loop above with i as counter
FlashCardView *subview = [[FlashCardView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
subview.delegate = self;
subview.viewNum=i+10; //My attempt at a workaround but I cannot get the view with this later so it is not very helpful
[subview setTag:i+10]; //Tried this and subview.tag=i+10;
NSLog(@"%d", subview.tag); //Prints correctly
//Gets added to parent later
```

This `NSLog` logs the correct tag, however when I log the tag in the `UIView` subclass, it always returns its tag as `1`. Also, if I print all the subviews of the parent in a later called method (In the `viewcontroller`), all of them have the tag 1.

Comment: include your code with for loop

Comment: means some where else in your code may be tag value updated once check your code.

Comment: Please post the code related to 'getting back the view from parentview'

Comment: @Sunny Thank you! I thought I was setting the tag for a different element but had typed it in tired! My fault :S

Comment: Why do you want the tag in the subclass? and where do you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell you why, but I can tell you how to find the problem. In your FlashCardView subclass, add this method:

```
- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)theTag
{
  assert(theTag != 1);
  [super setTag:theTag];
}
```

Then, when whatever is setting the tag to 1 does it, the assert will fire and you can look at the stack trace and see where its coming from.

Alternately, remove the assert, and put a breakpoint on the **super** message.

PS: make sure you enable exceptions!

Comment: Thanks for this, may be useful later and would also have lead me to find where I was accidentally setting the tag again.. Will mark your answer as solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for all your help, I found that I had accidentally typed in the subclass's variable when I meant to put in something else, setting the tag to 1. @Sunny, thanks for telling me to double-check.